# Do I need to create an instance of class to be tested with unittest?

Tags: python, class, unit-testing, python-3.x

Say I have:

```
class Calculator():
    def divide (self, divident, divisor):
        return divident/divisor`
```

And I want to test its divide method using Python 3.4 `unittest` module.

Does my code have to have instantiation of class to be able to test it? Ie, is the `setUp` method needed in the following test class:

```
class TestCalculator(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.calc = src.calculator.Calculator()
    def test_divide_by_zero(self):
        self.assertRaises(ZeroDivisionError, self.calc(0, 1))
```

Comment: Yes, if you want to test an instance of a class, you usually need to create one to have an instance to test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it has a `self` parameter it is an instance method, so you need an instance.

If it didn't have `self` you could make it a `@classmethod` or a `@staticmethod`, see [what's the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python).

As you don't use the `self` parameter it should probably not be an instance method. But you could just have a function instead and no class at all:

```
# calculator.py

def divide(dividend, divisor):
    return dividend / divisor
```

Comment: Perhaps my example was oversimplified, but your `As it has a self parameter it is an instance method, so you need an instance.` answers the question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you do. Whether you re-instantiate the class for each test case, or only once in setUp, depends on whether you need a fresh instance of the class for each test (for example, because your class carries a lot of internal state).

Comment: However, this method doesn't use any internal state, and the class doesn't carry any.

Comment: @PeterWood indeed. Just thought I'd mention that in case a further refinement introduces, say, memory variables to this calculator